# Convolutional neural network model not learning anything in keras

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network

I have this convolutional neural network in Keras:

```
storefeaturesInfo = Input(shape=(21,), name='storefeatures')
storefeaturesInfo_x=Dense(64,activation='relu')(storefeaturesInfo)

next48additionalInfo=Input(shape=(None, 8), name='next48additionalInfo')
x_next48additionalInfo=GRU(32)(next48additionalInfo)
next48additionalInfo_x=Dense(64,activation='relu')(x_next48additionalInfo)

input1 = Input(shape=(None, 10), name='firstfewtimesteps')    
x=Conv1D(24, 3, activation='relu', padding="causal")(input1)
x=BatchNormalization()(x)
x=Conv1D(32, 3, activation='relu', padding="causal")(x)
x=BatchNormalization()(x)
x=Conv1D(64, 3, activation='relu', padding="causal")(x)
x=BatchNormalization()(x)
x=Conv1D(128, 3, activation='relu', padding="causal")(x)
x=BatchNormalization()(x)
x=Conv1D(256, 3, activation='relu', padding="causal")(x)
x=BatchNormalization()(x)
x=Conv1D(512, 3, activation='relu', padding="causal")(x)
x=BatchNormalization()(x)
x=GlobalMaxPool1D()(x)
x=Dropout(0.25)(x)
x=Dense(512,activation='relu')(x)
x=Dense(256,activation='relu')(x)
x=Dense(128,activation='relu')(x)
x=Dense(64,activation='relu')(x)
x=Dropout(0.25)(x)

output_48=[]
finalInput = keras.layers.concatenate([x,storefeaturesInfo_x, next48additionalInfo_x])
for i in range(48):
    target=Dense(1, activation="relu", name=str(i))(finalInput)
    output_48.append(target)

model = Model([input1,storefeaturesInfo,next48additionalInfo], output_48)
model.compile(optimizer=adam,loss=mse,loss_weights=z)
```

I am trying to forecast sales as in this challenge (https://www.kaggle.com/c/rossmann-store-sales). The first Input, storefeaturesInfo consists of a 21 valued vector for a total of 1100 stores shaped: (1100,21), second layer describes the additional information for the model for the days that it is trying to forecast for such as whether the store is open or closed. I concatenate all this input and stack 48 dense layers as that is the number of predictions I need for future. I use 48 different layers because I weight them differently.

I train the model using a sliding window mechanism, given the past 12 weeks of data predict for the next 48 days. I slide this window for a total time length of 900 days. However, the model fails very badly at capturing any information at all, performing just barely better than predicting the historical average. The learning curves look like this:

[image: Trained with different learning rates]

What these curves show are the validation error for the second last 48 points, the goal is then to predict the 48 after these and submit the solution to Kaggle. 
I post this question to have a reason why this is failing.

Comment: Please include your model compilation code

Comment: I have added it now